# Disable mouse dropping text into a JTextField and allow paste keypressed event

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How to disable mouse dropping text into a `JTextField` and allow keypressed event (<kbd>ctrl + v</kbd>)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

> > jTextField.setDropTarget(null);